# Adding icon image to css class for html elements

Tags: html, css

I need to add icon image to HTML elements like this in case of font awesome and bootstrap.

Like this

[image]

for example I need to associate icon image with css class. Let say class name is ico and if I do something like this

```
 <a href="#" class="ico">Email Link</a>
```

Then it should appear as in the image above.

How can I accomplish this very important feature for UI design using CSS?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
.ico:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 40px;  /*height of icon */
    width: 40px;  /*width of icon */
    position: absolute;
      /*where to replace the icon */
    top: 0px;
    left: -40px;
      /*background */
    background: #F8E6AE url(ico.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

You can do that using `pseudo elements`

```css
.ico{
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.ico:before{
    content: '';
    background:url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSj3XfIpf-OOJRCcWz4iN2CU3qMKVVbj0p0bRvKNGVo1U9pk_8ZIlyR8pWreA');
    background-size:cover;
        position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="ico">Email Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="ico">Another Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a very simple way!
Just wrap the Icon inside the `<a>` tag instead of giving the `<a>` tag the class of the Icon:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-icon"></i>Email Link</a>
```

I'm using the `fas fa-icon` class to represent the use of the fontawesome library, you must specify your own icon.
Here's another smart tip for you to use in the `<a href="">` tag:
Add mailto and then the mail you want to send a mail to. Example:

```
<a href="mailto:example@yoursite.com"><i class="fas fa-icon"></i></a>
```

This opens the default mail application on the computer with the receiver already filled in as 'example@yoursite.com'!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.question-title{        
        display:block;
        padding-left:30px;
    }
    .question-title:before{
        content: '';
        background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrSlg.jpg');
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        position:absolute;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        margin-left:-30px;
       
    }
```

```html
<div class="questions-list">
   <div class="question-item status-open">
      <header class="question-title" >
         Question One                                       
      </header> 
   </div>
   <div class="question-item status-resolved">
      <header class="question-title">
         Question Two                                       
      </header>
   </div>
</div>
```